# First iteration jumping four rows instead of the expected one row

Tags: excel, vba

Why is my first iteration in `Sub throughCols` that is intended to move one row down each time jumping four rows?

```
Option Explicit

Dim txt As String
Dim i As Long
Dim strTest As String
Dim strArray() As String
Dim lCaseOn As Boolean
Dim firstRow As Long, startIt As Long
Dim thisCell As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim resetAddress As Range


Sub throughCols()

' Dim thisCell As Range

' get start and end of column data
' NB sheet name is hard coded twice
Call dataRange
startIt = firstRow + 1

For i = 1 To 8 Step 1
    ' after testing use startIt To lastRow Step 1
    ' by using activeCell I dont have to pass range through to the sub
    Sheets("test").Range("B" & i).Select
    MsgBox "this is itteration " & i & " which will output to " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Address
    Call arrayManip

    Call cleanTxt(txt)
Next i

End Sub


Sub arrayManip()

' clear out all data
Erase strArray
txt = ""

'set default case
lCaseOn = False

' string into an array using a " " separator
strTest = WorksheetFunction.Proper(ActiveCell.Value)
strTest = Replace(strTest, "-", " - ")
strTest = Replace(strTest, "‘", " ‘ ")
strArray = Split(strTest, " ")

' itterate through array looking to make text formats

For i = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)
    If strArray(i) = "-" Then
        lCaseOn = True
        GoTo NextIteration
    End If

    If strArray(i) = "‘" Then
        lCaseOn = True

        GoTo NextIteration
    End If
    If lCaseOn Then
        strArray(i) = LCase(strArray(i))
        lCaseOn = False
NextIteration:
    End If

    Next
End Sub

Function cleanTxt(txt)

' loop through the array to build up a text string
For i = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)
    txt = txt & strArray(i) & " "
Next i

' remove the space
txt = Trim(Replace(txt, " - ", "-"))
txt = Trim(Replace(txt, " ‘ ", "‘"))

' MsgBox "active cell is " & activeCell.Address
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select: ActiveCell.Value = txt

' MsgBox "final output would be " & txt & " to " & activeCell.Address
' this is a thumb suck to attempt to reset the active cell to the itteration address that started it
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Select
MsgBox "next itteration should start with active cell set as " & ActiveCell.Address

End Function
Sub dataRange()

With Sheets("test").Columns("B")

    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) = 0 Then '<--| if no data whatever
        MsgBox "Sorry: no data"
    Else
    With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<--| reference its cells with constant (i.e, not derived from formulas) values)
        firstRow = .Areas(1).Row
        lastRow = .Areas(.Areas.Count).Cells(.Areas(.Areas.Count).Rows.Count).Row
    End With
        ' MsgBox "the first row is " & firstRow
        ' MsgBox "last row is " & lastRow
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Your `i` is a global variable whose value is changed by some of the subs that you are calling in the loop. Don't use global variables without a good reason, something which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: You are a highly evolved genius- now how do I send you compliments when you have done a comment not an answer?

Comment: @JohnColeman `i` isn't global at all, it's a *private field*. The issue remains though: its scope is too wide and multiple procedures are accessing it.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I was using "global" in a generic sense as the counterpart to "local" in just about any programming language rather than as a technical term in VBA's scoping rules.

Comment: @MatsMug - curious - I have never heard of the term private field in VBA - can't find it on MSDN - where does it come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring your `i` variable at *module scope*, which makes it accessible everywhere within the module; it's modified when you call `arrayManip` and the value changes.

If you declare a *local* `ind` variable inside this routine it won't happen, because the variable will only be accessible to the scope it's declared in. Try the code below:

```
Sub throughCols()

' Dim thisCell As Range
Dim ind As Long  '<-- DECLARE local variable
' get start and end of column data
' NB sheet name is hard coded twice
Call dataRange
startIt = firstRow + 1

' ===== loop on ind and not i (changes when you call arrayManip) ====
For ind = 1 To 8 ' Step 1 <-- actually not needed, that's the default increment value
    ' after testing use startIt To lastRow Step 1
    ' by using activeCell I dont have to pass range through to the sub
    Sheets("test").Range("B" & ind).Select
    MsgBox "this is itteration " & ind & " which will output to " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Address
    Call arrayManip

    Call cleanTxt(txt)
Next ind

End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim` used at module level makes a `Private` field; "Global inside this module" is confusing wording, especially given the existence of the (deprecated) `Global` keyword, which implies `Public` scope. The variable is a *private field* (*field* denoting a module-scope variable), not "global" at all.

Comment: @Mat'sMug my explanation is not as good as your Mat, you know what I meant to say. If you could edit my explanation that would be great (I don't work for the RubberDuck project)

Comment: @Mat'sMug don't know, never knew how you join the team ?

Comment: This perhaps fixes the immediate problem, but I would be surprised if there isn't some other hidden bug due to unwanted interaction between these subs. OP should be encouraged to refactor their code instead of simply putting a band-aid on it.

Comment: If you want to show me how to "refactor" do please go ahead and teach - I have done one beginner VBA freebie course and that is the limit of my education. Student awaits...

Comment: @m4sterbunny have you tried implementing my code in yours ?

Comment: I didn't -John's comment made sense to me - the public v private variables (despite controversy about the terms). I amended my code to declare i in each sub and it works. I had never seen ind = so it is great that you exposed that as a possibility

Comment: @johncoleman thanks- please do refactor and post if you have the energy, I will learn more from someone gives feedback on code I have written than by reading a ton of articles.